# Implicit differentiation: $\mathrm d\left(\frac{t+2}{t-3}\right) / \mathrm d\left(\frac{3t+1}{t-4}\right)$

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, implicit-differentiation

So I have:

$$y=\frac{t+2}{t-3},\qquad x=\frac{3t+1}{t-4}$$

What is $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ when $t=1$?

I got $\dfrac{45}{52}$ but wanted to check the answer.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 0):

$dy/dx=(dy/dt)/(dx/dt)=(-5/(x-3)^2)/(-13/(x-4)^2)$
By substituting $t=1$, you can get $dy/dx=(-5/4)/(-13/9)=45/52$